# Checking the convergence of series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Here is the given series 3/(9n+1), decide whether it converges or diverges.
I used the ratio test only to end up with the ratio=1.
I know this is harmonic series but it is smaller than 1/n, therefore i cannot conclude it diverges. 
Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ratio and root tests are very crude and won't work here.  Have you tried comparison oar limit comparison?

Comment: with 1/n you mean?

Comment: because then using limit comparison test with 1/n i found it to be divergent. is that right?

Comment: Yes.  That is what I had hoped you would do. I didn't want to "spoil" the problem for you.

Comment: ahh i see, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 3):

$$ \frac{3}{9n+1} \ge 
   \frac{1}{9n+1} \ge 
   \frac{1}{9n+9} \ge  
   \frac{1}{9(n+1)} \ge
   \frac{1}{9} \frac{1}{n+1}
$$

At which point you should be able to figure that out...

Comment: are u trying to show that this series is greater than the divergent series therefore it is divergent?

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$
\frac{3}{9n+1}\geq \frac{3}{9n+9}=\frac{1}{3(n+1)}.
$$
Since $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3(n+1)}$ is disvergent, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{3}{9n+1}$.

Comment: @d13: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*

$$\dfrac{3}{9 n+1} \geqslant \dfrac{3}{12n}=\dfrac{1}{4}\cdot \dfrac{1}{n}$$